# Insight Symfony: A Symfony application should be bootable

Tags: php, symfony

Cant create dir insight_cache, Upgraded to Symfony 5 from Symfony 4.3

[image]

```
    RuntimeException: Unable to create the cache directory(/insight_cache)
 in /home/foobar/code/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:624
Stack trace:
#0 /home/foobar/code/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(544): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer()
#1 /home/foobar/code/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(126): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer()
#2 /home/foobar/code/app/AppKernel.php(99): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
#3 /home/foobar/code/app/InsightAppKernel.php(15) : eval()'d code(7): AppKernel->boot()
#4 /home/foobar/code/app/InsightAppKernel.php(15): eval()
#5 {main}
```

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Is it okay now ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your path is absolute, meaning it will try the root of your drive?

```
RuntimeException: Unable to create the cache directory(/insight_cache)
```

Try editing the cache file location to NOT begin with a `/`.